# Getting duplicate node values when parsing XML file using RapidXML

Tags: c++, xml, rapidxml

I need to read a simple XML file using RapidXML. I've loaded the XML file into a string variable and passed it to the parser. I need to get all nodes names and values, if those exist.
My problem is that the following values end up as duplicates:

- stepID->value
- stepHeading1->value
- stepText->value

Here's a picture describing the problem:

[image: Image showing the problem]

Why does my code give me all of these duplicated values if the stepID, stepHeading1 and stepText nodes doesn't have have any child nodes? Also, why doesn't the code give me duplicate node names, when the node values turn out that way?

------------ XML file below------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<game>
    <step>
        <stepID>Name</stepID>
        <stepHeading1>Title1</stepHeading1>
        <stepHeading2></stepHeading2>
        <stepHeading3></stepHeading3>
        <stepHeading4></stepHeading4>
        <stepHeading5></stepHeading5>
        <stepHeading6></stepHeading6>
        <stepText>First Step First Step First Step </stepText>
        <link>
            <linkStepID>First Link Name</linkStepID>
            <linkText>First Link Text</linkText>
        </link>
    </step>
</game>
```

------------ code below------------

```
xml_document<>doc;
doc.parse<0>(&( dataForParser1.getLoadedXMLfile() )[0]);

xml_node<> *rootNode = doc.first_node();
xml_node <> *pStep = 0;
xml_node <> *pDiff = 0;
xml_node <> *pLink = 0;

for (xml_node <> *pStep = rootNode->first_node("step"); pStep; pStep = pStep->next_sibling())
{
    cout << pStep->name() << "   " << pStep->value() << endl;

    for (xml_node <> *pDiff = pStep->first_node(); pDiff; pDiff = pDiff->next_sibling())
    {
        cout << pDiff->name() << "   " << pDiff->value() << endl;

        for (xml_node <> *pLink = pDiff->first_node(); pLink; pLink = pLink->next_sibling())
        {
            cout << pLink->name() << "   " << pLink->value() << endl;
        }
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're having is due to the flag that you're applying to the `parse` method:

```
doc.parse<0>(&( dataForParser1.getLoadedXMLfile() )[0]);
```

When 0 is used here, the node data will be converted into a separate child node.

Try using `parse<1>` instead and the data should remain in the parent node.

This info can be found in the `rapidxml.hpp` file, among other flags:

```
//! Parse flag instructing the parser to not create data nodes. 
//! Text of first data node will still be placed in value of parent element, unless rapidxml::parse_no_element_values flag is also specified.
//! Can be combined with other flags by use of | operator.
//! <br><br>
//! See xml_document::parse() function.
const int parse_no_data_nodes = 0x1;
```

Comment: It works! Thanks Mir178249 for help and editing my post :)

Comment: @wojtek: Great. Happy to help!